# How to change controller's property value inside acceptance test?

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to alter the controller's property value inside acceptance test?

```
test('should add new post', function(assert) {
  visit('/posts/new');
  fillIn('input.title', 'My new post');
  click('button.submit');
  andThen(() => assert.equal(find('ul.posts li:first').text(), 'My new post'));
});
```

For example, I would like to set the default value for an input before running the test.

Comment: Keep in mind: Acceptance tests are supposed to simulate how your app actually works in response to user interaction, so it's usually not a good idea to manually alter a controller's property like this.  You should either get to the desired state via DOM interaction, or move this test to Integration or Unit.

Comment: Or do I have a way to change stub model() inside acceptance test ?

Comment: What are you using to stub your data?  I highly recommend `ember-cli-mirage`: http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/.  It allows you to set up your mock database with the custom objects you want for each test.

Comment: I thought it only works with ember data

Comment: Nope, you don't need ember-data.  It basically just intercepts all API requests, and returns what you want it to

Comment: I am asking this is because inside my model it returns a static data and not actually calling any API

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138134/discussion-between-dwenzel-and-li-xinyang).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access to application registry and lookup the controller.

`moduleForAcceptance` sets application.

```
test('should add new post', function(assert) {
  let controller = this.application.__container__.lookup('controller:posts/new');  
  controller.set('val', 'default');

  visit('/posts/new');
  fillIn('input.title', 'My new post');
  click('button.submit');
  andThen(() => assert.equal(find('ul.posts li:first').text(), 'My new post'));
});
```

Please take a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/1b8babfda659ff02b5766dc36ff022d3)

Answer (score 4):

The currently accepted answer by @ebrahim-pasbani is correct for any Ember v 2.x apps that are using the legacy QUnit Testing API by `ember-cli-qunit@4.1.0` or lower.

Please note though, that in case that you are using the more recent QUnit Testing API that is available in your app if you are either

- using `ember-cli-qunit@4.2.0` or greater or
- working on a new Ember v3.x app

the following will work by leveraging the public `owner` API and the `setupApplicationTest` helper:

```
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import { setupApplicationTest } from 'ember-qunit';
import { visit, fillIn, click, find } from '@ember/test-helpers';
import { run } from '@ember/runloop';

module('Acceptance | posts', function(hooks) {
  setupApplicationTest(hooks);

  test('should add new post', async function(assert) {
    await run(() => this.owner.lookup('controller:posts/new').set('val', 'default'));
    await visit('/posts/new');
    await fillIn('input.title', 'My new post');
    await click('button.submit');
    assert.equal(find('ul.posts li:first').textContent.trim(), 'My new post');
  });
});
```

If you are unfamiliar with the new QUnit Testing API yet, I can recommend reading Robert Jackson's [introduction to the API](https://www.rwjblue.com/2017/10/23/ember-qunit-simplication/), the updated [official Testing Guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/testing/) as well as the [original RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0232-simplify-qunit-testing-api.md) for even more context.